# How to check if two devices are mounted in macOS?

Tags: bash, macos

I want two external HDs to synchronize as soon as they are both connected at the same time.

I installed LaunchControl which will run a bash script as soon as something is mounted. The script should check if there are two devices called `foo` and `bar` and only then do something.

This is what I have:

```
if mount | grep "/Volumes/foo" > /dev/null; then
    echo "One is connected"
fi
```

Every attempt to add a second check for `bar` failed. This is what I tried:

```
if mount | [grep "/Volumes/foo" > /dev/null] && [grep "/Volumes/bar" > /dev/null]; then
    echo "Both are connected"
fi
```

Comment: `if grep -q "/Volumes/foo" <(mount) && grep -q "/Volumes/bar" <(mount); then ...; fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working code doesn't have `[]` around the call to `grep`, why did you think you needed to add that when doing multiple tests?

```
if mount | grep "/Volumes/foo" > /dev/null && mount | grep "/Volumes/bar" > /dev/null; then
    echo "Both are connected"
fi
```

Instead of redirecting to `/dev/null` you can use the `-q` option to `grep`.

```
if mount | grep -q "/Volumes/foo" && mount | grep -q "/Volumes/bar"; then
    echo "Both are connected"
fi
```